# How to check out test code in squeak for the "Inbox"?

Tags: repository, smalltalk, squeak

What is the process in Squeak to check out some test code for the *Inbox*, e.g. from the package `KernelTests-Numbers`? Should I have a local repo and save my extended version in it?

YouTube has a [good screencast](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IWr5Lj8pDRk&list=PL61A023880D3529DB&index=38) for creating a local repo, but no videos on "how to checkout in *Inbox*".

Answer (score 2):

The video that you found was a good clue. While adding the local repository, they clicked on "directory". To add the inbox, click on "HTTP" instead, and change the URL template to 'http://source.squeak.org/inbox'.

p.s. IMHO really basic questions like this would be better asked on the Squeak Beginner list (http://lists.squeak.org/mailman/listinfo/beginners). It seems to me that this process should be better documented and asking there will both allow you to have a give and take more easily then peppering SO with multiple questions, as well as give them the opportunity to see the apparent lack of clarity in the current documentation.

p.p.s. Although you obviously know this since you've already made your change, there seems to be a little confusion in the terminology... You don't have to "checkout" anything. Squeak does not use locking in its VCS. The package in question is already in a Squeak trunk image. Make your changes locally in such an image, and then *commit* to the inbox via the Monticello Browser. From there, a core developer will integrate the changes if approved.

Comment: thanks sean, but my prev question in SO had the reason that I didn't know so much about the organisation structure of squeak-dev etc. Now I'm getting more and more the picture.

Comment: I understand. I'm suggesting that the process might be more efficient for all involved on the mailing list

Comment: Off: Mailing lists have no features like searching, tagging, voting. How to say it very cool... ML are the past, SO is the future. ;-) Maybe my question is in the wrong stack exchange community?!?

Comment: Sounds like just a difference of opinion... And FYI there's a Nabble mirror with search, which I find indispensable

Comment: Forums like Stack Exchange come and go. The Squeak mailing list exists since 1996 and it still is the actual home of the community, where you find the real experts.

Comment: @bartak were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @BertFreudenberg: Trolling?!? ifTrue: Post stamps, overhead projector and blackboards... yes, good old things which still have an use for some communities. Who needs electric kettles today... and flat screens... AND Caps-Locks ;-p ifFalse: I will look at this expert mailing list. :-)

Comment: @SeanDeNigris: Thanks for the hint with Nabble. I will try it out. On this post I got my answer and in current post I got good information about squeak-community